# INNER JOIN e FOREACH

Tags: php

Preciso mostrar o nome da cor de uma tabela, em resultado de outra.
Código:

```
<?php 
    $sqlPint = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cor_fundo AS c 
                                    INNER JOIN produto AS p
                                    ON c.cor_fundo_id = p.produto_cor_fundo                                     
                                    WHERE c.ativo = 1 AND p.produto_id = '".$cod."' 
                                    ORDER BY c.cor_fundo_nome ASC");
    if (mysql_num_rows($sqlPint)== true):
        while ($lnPint = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlPint)):                                          

    $checked = explode(',', $lnPint['produto_cor_fundo']);  

    foreach ($checked as $row){
            $nome = $row['cor_fundo_nome'];
            $id = $row['cor_fundo_id'];
?>                                      

<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="product-chooser-item">              
        <div class="">
            <span class="title tt_uppercase"><?=$row['cor_fundo_nome']?></span>
            <input type="radio" name="produto_pintura_fundo"  value="<?=$id?>">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<? } endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Na tabela produto está gravado apenas os id's que vem da tabela cor_fundo como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso mostrar o nome das cores que está na tabela cor_fundo ao invés dos id's que estão na tabela produtos.

Na página está mostrando assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teria que aparecer os nomes e não os números.

Answer (score 1):

O relacionamento existente entre sua tabelas <kbd>produto</kbd> e <kbd>cor_fundo</kbd> é de `1:N`.

> Um produto pode conter muitas cores.

Pelo menos foi o que entendi da sua imagem. No entanto apesar de ter construído uma tabela separada para cores, não criou uma tabela de relacionamento entre as tabelas. Aonde seria armazenado o id da cor e o id do produto ao invés disso concatenou dentro de um campo `produto_cor_fundo` da tabela <kbd>produto</kbd> as `ids` das cores separados por virgula.

É completamente desaconselhável seguir dessa maneira!

Na sua querie você fez:

```
SELECT * FROM cor_fundo AS c INNER JOIN produto AS p
ON c.cor_fundo_id = p.produto_cor_fundo                                     
WHERE c.ativo = 1 AND p.produto_id = '".$cod."' 
ORDER BY c.cor_fundo_nome ASC
```

Descrevendo sua querie, ela faz o seguinte:

> Selecionar todos os campos da tabela <kbd>cor_fundo</kbd> relacionando com a tabela <kbd>produto</kbd> aonde o campo `cor_fundo_id` é igual ao campo `produto_cor_fundo`. 
>   Enquanto o campo `ativo` deve ser igual a 1 e o campo `produto_id` dever ser igual a variável `$cod`, ordenando ascendente pelo nome da cor.

Repare que não irá funcionar porque ao invés de ter apenas uma id de cor por linha de produto, existe uma concatenação de ids no campo `produto_cor_fundo` da tabela <kbd>produto</kbd>

Existem duas formas de corrigir esse problema:

## 1ª maneira

Persistir no erro de modelagem também conhecido como POG (programação orientada a gambiarra).

```
 $checked = explode(',', $lnPint['produto_cor_fundo']);  

 foreach ($checked as $row){
   $id = $row['cor_fundo_id'];       
   $sqlPint = mysql_query("SELECT cor_fundo_nome FROM cor_fundo WHERE 
   cor_fundo_id =".$id);
```

Criar um nova querie dentro do seu `foreach` e buscar os nomes de todas as cores para cada linha de produto buscada na querie anterior.

> O que é completamente desaconselhável porque se tiver um produto com 50 cores irá influenciar completamente a performance da sua aplicação. E mesmo que pense que são poucas cores, se houver alguns poucos acessos também vai gerar fila de espera pela consulta em seu servidor.

Consultas no banco de dados requer muita memoria, e gera gargalo por se tratar de leitura em disco rígido, lembrando que o tempo que leva para filtrar os resultados da querie, o seu servidor fica em espera de resposta e também consumindo recursos.

## 2ª Maneira, e a mais correta:

Crie uma nova tabela chamada <kbd>produto_cores</kbd>, crie um campo `produto_cores_id` que sera a chave primária dessa tabela, e crie ainda chaves compostas para essa tabela: `produto_id` e `cor_fundo_id`, e faça um relacionamento de `1:N` usando essas duas chaves das tabelas <kbd>produto</kbd> e <kbd>cor_fundo</kbd>. A esse tipo modelagem se da o nome de chave primária composta.

> Você precisa também alterar suas rotinas de inserção do produto e de update no banco de dados. Para inserir ou atualizar nessa nova tabela as ids do produto e as ids de suas cores.

Em seguida altere sua querie de consulta para isso:

```
 SELECT * FROM produto_cores pc 
 INNER JOIN produto p ON p.produto_id = pc.produto_id 
 INNER JOIN cores_fundo cf ON cf.cor_fundo_id = pc.cor_fundo_id 
 WHERE cf.ativo = 1 AND p.produto_id = ".$cod."
 ORDER BY cf.cor_fundo_nome ASC;
```

Pronto você agora tem acesso as cores de seus produtos. Repare, que vai dar um trabalhinho para corrigir, mas no entanto executara apenas uma querie para buscar os resultados pretendidos, e sobre alta demanda de acessos a performance não decaí, não gera gargalos no servidor.

É importante que consulte também sobre: (DER) DIAGRAMA DE ENTIDADES DE RELACIONAMENTO para os próximos sistemas, que desejar montar.

Comment: Rafael, vou fazer algumas alterações na sua resposta, com intuito de diminuir o que pode ser considerado como poluição visual

Comment: Pode mandar bala! Obrigado marcelo.

Comment: Fiz mais uma revisão na sua resposta, com uma pequena correção sobre chave primaria composta.... caso ache que alterei em muito a sua intenção original de resposta, pode [reverter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrGWr.png) a publicação pra uma versão anterior.

Comment: Marcelo há duas formas de fazer: definir uma chave com auto incremento mais dois atributos com a chave primaria das tabelas que se relacionam e definir uma UNIQUE KEY composta dos atributos, ou como eu tinha dito usar as duas chaves primarias das tabelas que se relacionam para gerar um primary key composta na nova tabela, também funciona. De fato nunca fui contra a forma que botou ali, até utilizo. Mas na universidade ai entra a chata  teoria, se fizesse isso em uma questão era marcada como errada! kkkk. Novamente obrigado pela edição.